# Certain URLs for Inserting Pictures into Excel Sheet Returns a Run Time Error

Tags: vba, excel, macros, runtime-error

I have a spreadsheet that has some macro created to take picture url's from one column to display in another. 
When I run the macro, it goes smoothly until I reach url's that look like these ones:

[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/513aNHvKu3L.*SL160*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/513aNHvKu3L._SL160_.jpg)

http://i.upcindex.com/i/WjI5dlpjMnhwYldGblpYTXViV0ZqZVhNdVkyOXRMMmx6TDJsdFlXZGxMMDFEV1M5d2NtOWtkV04wY3k4NUwyOXdkR2x0YVhwbFpDOHpNekF3TnpneFgyWndlQzUwYVdZL2QybGtQVE13TUNabWJYUTlhbkJsWnlaeGJIUTlNVEF3MnhsYzNWamEzTQ,,.jpg

I then receive a Run Time error and the program stops working.
When I click on these urls or paste them into a browser an image does appear.

Is there a way to get the macro to be a little more forgiving with these kind of urls? So, that I can pull the images from them.

Here's the code I am using:

```
Sub InstallPictures() 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 
Dim url_column As Range 
Dim image_column As Range 
 'column with url...
Set url_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("V") 
 'column where image will be inserted
Set image_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("W") 
Dim i As Long 
For i = 2 To url_column.Cells.Count 
    Set Picture = image_column.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert(url_column.Cells(i).Value) 
    Picture.Left = image_column.Cells(i).Left 
    Picture.Top = image_column.Cells(i).Top 
    Picture.Height = 40 
    image_column.Cells(i).EntireRow.RowHeight = 40 
Next 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Background***

While I was available to reproduce the error, I do not understand why this happens specifically in those 2 URLs; I think either one of the following conditions *may be* happening:

a) It may have something to do with either the "." and ","

b) DDoS protection used for those sites -just my guess-

***Disclaimer: This is a work-around***

This should log the addresses that could not be retrieved at the moment -and continue running for the ones that can-.

```
Sub InstallPictures()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim url_column As Range
Dim image_column As Range
 'column with url...
Set url_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("V")
 'column where image will be inserted
Set image_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("W")
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To url_column.Cells.Count
    On Error GoTo Err01InstallPictures
    Set Picture = image_column.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert(url_column.Cells(i).Value)
    Picture.Left = image_column.Cells(i).Left
    Picture.Top = image_column.Cells(i).Top
    Picture.Height = 40
    image_column.Cells(i).EntireRow.RowHeight = 40
    If 1 = 2 Then '99. If error only falls here if error is detected
Err01InstallPictures:
    image_column.Cells(i).Value = url_column.Cells(i).Value
    image_column.Cells(i).Interior.Color = vbRed
    On Error GoTo -1
    End If '99. If error only falls here if error is detected
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

**Further details**

The only thing extra that I tried was using the macro developer to see why it was doing it in the normal interface but by VBA was not, sadly, no conclusion was determined on why this is happening.

Comment: Sgdva, THANK YOU. Your revisions "work-a-rounds" helps tremendously. I ran the new Macro through hundreds of url's and instead of receiving the Run Time error, the url's mostly-- the ones that began with ....(http://ecx.images..) were highlighted in red instead and did not produce images. I'm curious as to why the http://ecx.images...will not execute, but your guesses makes sense.

Comment: So, the solution above is great...Though, I would still love to know--why, my url's that begin with (http://ecx.images...) have issues, even though those link open up just fine in a browser? Is it the DDoS protection  that Sgdva was talking about? That's a first time with me and not sure what that is yet..but will research.

Comment: Glad to help, I am curious as well, but, since we cannot have access to the DDoS protection of these sites, I am afraid it is most likely that only their Technical support would available to answer that -and since it is a security matter, I think is likely that we won't know :) -